# Nested for loop errors

Tags: arduino-uno

Ok, I am trying to make 2 LEDs run at two different speeds.

Here is the code I am using:

```
void setup() {


  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
}

for ( ; ; ) {
  for ( ; ; ) {
   digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
   delay(250);
   digitalWrite(12, LOW);
   delay(250);
  }
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  delay(500);
}
```

This code unfortunately returns this error:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before 'for'
 for ( ; ; ) {
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Where is your loop function...?

Comment: where should it be?

Comment: Around your (pointless) for loops?

Comment: Like what would that code look like?

Comment: It would look like all the examples in the IDE - especially the blink example.

Answer (score 0):

As Majenko's comments are suggesting you're missing the `loop` function here - which is not just eye candy but essential. It is the basic structure of the [sketches](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BareMinimum) to have two methods on the highest (user accessible) level: `void setup()` and `void loop()`. `setup` is run exactly once at the beginning of your program. Following that `loop` is looped (hence the name) forever.

This is what it should look like:

```
void setup() {
  // doing the setup
}

void loop() {
    for ( ; ; ) {
        for ( ; ; ) {
            // something
        }
        // something else
    }
}
```

However (and again Majenko's comment hints it) `something else` is never going to be executed as the inner loop is never exited. This [tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay) (per Majenko's comment) should get you started. See also: [www.arduino.cc](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples) with many more tutorials worth studying.

Comment: so how do I make it run both at the same time?

Comment: Start with the BlinkWithoutDelay example.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your question is so basic it means you didn't spend any time to look any example out there, not even after Majenko has clearly pointed out you can find the answer to your question in the many examples out there.

Once that is clear here follow the code you are looking for, but using it as it is without knowing what you are doing is not going to help you. Not to mention not many will be willing to help somebody with the attitude you are demonstrating.

```
#define LED_1 5
#define LED_2 6

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_2, OUTPUT);
}

long one, two;
bool led_1, led_2;

void loop() {
  if (millis() - one >= 250) {
    digitalWrite(LED_1, led_1++);
    one = millis();
  }

  if (millis() - two >= 500) {
    digitalWrite(LED_2, led_2++);
    two = millis();
  }
}
```

Comment: One correction, never compare millis() like that. Always make `>=`, because it will be rarely equal to 250 or 500 and it will never run code.

Comment: You are 100% right, thanks for spotting the mistake: fix applied. For those reading the comment afterwards, I erroneously had an equality comparison `==` instead of a greater than comparison `>=` on the two if statements.

Answer (score 0):

You have a compiler error because you have executable code outside a function. In particular your first "for" loop.

Second, an infinite loop inside an infinite loop is not particularly useful.

> so how do I make it run both at the same time?

Ah yes, well unless you have multiple CPUs you don't run multiple things "at the same time". You do one thing, and then another thing.

I have an article about this general idea here:

http://www.gammon.com.au/blink

To save having to necessarily go to that link, here is an example from that page which blinks two LEDs at different rates:

```
// Which pins are connected to which LED
const byte greenLED = 12;
const byte redLED = 13;

// Time periods of blinks in milliseconds (1000 to a second).
const unsigned long greenLEDinterval = 500;
const unsigned long redLEDinterval = 1000;

// Variable holding the timer value so far. One for each "Timer"
unsigned long greenLEDtimer;
unsigned long redLEDtimer;

void setup () 
  {
  pinMode (greenLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (redLED, OUTPUT);
  greenLEDtimer = millis ();
  redLEDtimer = millis ();
  }  // end of setup

void toggleGreenLED ()
  {
   if (digitalRead (greenLED) == LOW)
      digitalWrite (greenLED, HIGH);
   else
      digitalWrite (greenLED, LOW);

  // remember when we toggled it
  greenLEDtimer = millis ();  
  }  // end of toggleGreenLED

void toggleRedLED ()
  {
   if (digitalRead (redLED) == LOW)
      digitalWrite (redLED, HIGH);
   else
      digitalWrite (redLED, LOW);

  // remember when we toggled it
  redLEDtimer = millis ();  
  }  // end of toggleRedLED

void loop ()
  {

  // Handling the blink of one LED.
  if ( (millis () - greenLEDtimer) >= greenLEDinterval)
     toggleGreenLED ();

  // The other LED is controlled the same way. Repeat for more LEDs
  if ( (millis () - redLEDtimer) >= redLEDinterval) 
    toggleRedLED ();

/* Other code that needs to execute goes here.
   It will be called many thousand times per second because the above code
   does not wait for the LED blink interval to finish. */

}  // end of loop
```

In that code, in the main loop, the code uses `millis()` to find the current time, and if sufficient time has elapsed it does something useful. As an analogy, when you are cooking dinner you look at the clock from time to time, and if sufficient time has elapsed since you started cooking, you take the roast from the oven and eat it.